# Cin: wait for <ENTER>. Two continues cin.ignore do not work

Tags: c++, cin

Here is the code:

```
cout << "Press <ENTER> when you are ready to procceed..." << endl;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());
cin.clear();
...
cout << "Insert " << nominal << " rubbles into money acceptor and press <ENTER>" << endl;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());
cin.clear();
```

The first time it waits for  but the second one, it goes right throw it without any pause.

I tried to use just cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits::max(),'\n'); or cin.get() or cin.ignore() or getchar(). Nothing works.

I even tried to ask user to enter for a number:

```
{cout << "eof: " << cin.eof(); int num; cin >> num; cout << "eof: " << cin.eof(); }
```

This does not work for the second time either! It reads '32767' from cin on the second call.
And outputs:

```
eof: 0
eof: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't really clear to me what you are trying to do, or why. However, I wrote this simple test application, which works just fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Press enter to start\n";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    std::cout << "Press enter again to begin data entry\n";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    int i, j;

    std::cout << "Enter a value for i\n";
    std::cin >> i;
    // skip any trailing characters after the number the user entered
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    std::cout << "Enter a value for j\n";
    std::cin >> j;
    // skip any trailing characters after the number the user entered
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    std::cout << "i was " << i << ", j was " << j << "\n";

    std::cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    std::cout << "Press enter again to exit\n";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Leaving in the `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());` lines that you had in your code forces me to hit enter (to trigger the "ignore until `\n` code) and then hit control-D to send an EOF to trigger the second `ignore` call. I could not replicate your *"it goes right throughit without any pause"* condition.

This code built and ran correctly under GCC 4.7.2 and VS2013 Express.

Comment: Your code works. Can I have problems caused by SIGIO sygnal? Such sygnals are sent constantly right at the period of time when my second cin.ignore() is waiting for '\n'. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: @Arks hmm. Suddenly this sounds like a very different question! I suspect the answer is to use per-thread signal masking, and deal with SIGIO in a separate worker thread. I cannot really advise you on how to do that, however. You should perhaps ask a new question?

Comment: I'll make a research on per-thread signal masking first. Then I'll make a question if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
cin.sync()
```

maybe it will work...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Yes, I would do. But I'm not able to... I need 50 reputations.